# Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved .

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

Following is my WCF configuration. I published it in IIS and trying to connect to it from a Windows forms client.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<client />
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BindingConfiguration">
      <security>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>      
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="Service" behaviorConfiguration="BehaviorConfiguration">        
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" name="wsBinding" contract="WCFHttps.IService1" bindingConfiguration="BindingConfiguration"/>
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name= "BehaviorConfiguration">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceCredentials>            
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Windows"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<!--<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />-->
```

It throws an error while trying to add service reference in the test client.

```
    The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: '****/Service1.svc?wsdl'.
Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service ****/Service1.svc?wsdl.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

I have also granted read/write permissions for IIS_USRS over C:\Windows\Temp folder but still the problem persists. Can anyone suggest what's wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: What does your client config look like?  Are you using `wsHttpBinding` for the client? And is the security specified for the binding on the client the same as the service?

Answer (score 0):

**cause:** 
Cause of this error is simple when you try to refer the WCF service IIS tried to access C:\Windows\Temp folder. If ASP.NET or IIS_IUSER(based on the windows version) account doesn’t have access to this folder you will see this error.

**Solution:** 
Add ASP.NET or IIS_USER account to this folder or give admin rights to the user account you are running your application.

Configuring Tracing
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: I granted full permissions for IIS_IUSRS to the C:\Windows\Temp folder,  but it still doesn't work.

Comment: ` The client and service bindings may be mismatched.` This is probably the key here, but without seeing OP's client config it's hard to say for certain.

Answer (score 0):

In my case wrong namespace was specified in web.config file. It has to be same as namespace of your .svc file:

```
 <service name="NAMESPACE.SvcFileName">
    <endpoint contract="NAMESPACE.IContractName" />
  </service>
```

Example:

```
<service name="MyNameSpace.FileService">
<endpoint contract="MyNameSpace.IFileService" />
</service>
```

*(Unrelevant tags ommited in these samples)*